# No definition found for library function for vscode typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, gitignore

**In VSCode:**

---

I want to go to the definition of a library function included with some library with `const lib = require("lib")`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click is on, because I can jump to a function I defined, or like a `Math.function` function.

However, when I try to do this a **node-modules** library function i.e. `lib.utils.someFunction`, the **hovertext** says 'any' and the `ctrl+click` says "no definition found for someFunction". Installing the typescript language server doesn't seem to solve anything.

Tellingly, the **Node-Modules** folder doesn't appear on the left pane and is in my **gitIgnore**, but I don't know how to enable `ctrl+click` without changing that. However, the 'lib' module is installed into the node-modules folder and I can manually cd in in terminal.

Comment: Does `lib` come with a `index.d.ts` file? If not, then vscode won't be able to jump to the definition of any function defined in `lib`. Check out the [`DefinitelyTyped`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) github repo and see if definitions exist for `lib`

Comment: @smac89 yes, in the /node-modules/lib/build there is an index.d.ts that exports a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Does that `index.d.ts` have `utils.someFunction` declared? If so, something is probably off with your typescript setup in vscode. gitignore has nothing to do with it because it is normal to have `node_modules` in gitignore. You need to verify that you have the correct settings for typescript in vscode. See this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling)

Answer (score 0):

gitignore => Ignore the file when "git push".
I think you didn't have "lib" library function in local

If you want use https://www.npmjs.com/package/lib
You should use "npm install lib"

Comment: Node-Modules must be in  tsconfig.json same directory (normal situation